# Eigen no matching function for call .dot()?

Tags: c++, methods, eigen3

In my code I define a template class with an `operator()` that is defined as follows:

```
template<class Integrator, int ORDER>
inline double operator() (FiniteElement<Integrator, ORDER,2,3>& currentfe_,
                          int i, int j, int iq, int ic = 0)
{
    Real s = 0;

    Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1> grad_phi_i;
    Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1> grad_phi_j;

    grad_phi_i(0) = ...
    grad_phi_i(1) = ...
    grad_phi_j(0) = ...
    grad_phi_j(1) = ...

    s = grad_phi_i.dot(currentfe_.metric().dot(grad_phi_j));

    return s;
}
```

Where

```
currentfe_.metric()
```

Is a method of class `FiniteElement` returning a `Eigen::Matrix<double,2,2>`.

The error i get is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>::dot(Eigen::internal::scalar_product_traits<double, double>::ReturnType)’
s = grad_phi_i.dot(currentfe_.metric().dot(grad_phi_j));
```

And I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Matrix `.dot()` method is only for the scalar product between vectors (see the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a6be0cca648735d515cbf10863e73a639)).
[Here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html) you can see that the multiplication between a matrix and a vector is performed with `*`.

A possible solution is:

```
grad_phi_i*currentfe_.metric()*grad_phi_j.transpose()
```

Comment: To be precise, it does have a `.dot()` method but that's only for scalar products between two vectors, and the return type is thus a scalar.

Comment: @ggael is right. I'll edit the answer to clarify this point and provide a reference.